# Why predicate not a property of NSFetchRequest?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, design-patterns

NSFetchRequest has methods `predicate` and `setPredicate`. I wonder why Apple not make predicate a property of NSFetchRequest? That would make life a little bit easier.

More, it appears that NSFetchRequest has no properties at all.. What's the underlying principle behind this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's one very good reason it has no properties:

- NSFetchRequest was introduced with [Core Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Data) in Mac OS X 10.4.
- Properties were introduced with [Objective-C 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C_2.0) in Mac OS X
  10.5.

So the class predates the invention of Objective-C properties, and for whatever reason has never been revisited.

Answer (score 2):

You can write

```
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
```

even if `predicate` is not declared as property of `NSFetchRequest`. The compiler translates this to

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: I think you are right. Only that it's generally avoided to use dot syntax for non-property methods.